# How to draw selected instances with gl_InstanceID and glDrawElements...?

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry-instancing, gpu-instancing

I want to draw a selected number of instances using `glDrawElements...` but I don't know which function to use and how to set the parameters.

I set the `gl_InstanceID` in shader and set the shader data through SSBO:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &SSBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, SSBO);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, data_vector.size() * sizeof(data_type), data_vector.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, binding_index, SSBO);
```

I have an array `drawable_vector` contains `bool` to check if the vertex is drawn or not.

```
for(auto index = 0; index  < drawable_vector.size(); index ++){
    glDrawElements...(???)
}
```

I want to draw instance with ID `gl_instanceID` only when the `drawable_vector[index]` is `true`. The size of drawable_vector, data_vector and number of instances are the same.

Edit: Setup & render code

Setup:

```
//VAO
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

//VBO1 - Position
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO1);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3*sizeof(glm::vec4), vertices.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

//VBO2 - color
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3*sizeof(glm::vec4), colors.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

//EBO
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

//SSBO - models in shader
glGenBuffers(1, &SSBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, SSBO);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, models.size() * sizeof(glm::vec4), models.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 2, SSBO);

//Set data of shader
//in_pos
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO1);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *) 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
//in_color
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *) 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 0);
glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Shader:

```
#version 450 core
out vec4 frag_color;

in vec4 out_color;

void main()
{
    frag_color = out_color;
}
```

```
#version 430 core
layout (location = 0) in vec4 in_pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 in_color;
layout(std430, binding = 2) buffer DataBuffer
{
    mat4 in_models[];
} buffer_data;

uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

out vec4 out_color;

void main()
{
    out_color = in_color;
    gl_Position = projection * view * buffer_data.in_models[gl_InstanceID] * in_pos;

}
```

Render:

```
use_shader();
shader_set_view("view", view);
shader_set_projection("projection", projection);
update_models();
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, SSBO);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 2, SSBO[0]);
glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3, n_instances);

glfwSwapBuffers(window);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Hav to use the command @Yakov Galka mentioned and added gl_BaseInstance to the shader

```
void main()
{
    out_color = in_color;
    gl_Position = projection * view * buffer_data.in_models[gl_BaseInstance+gl_InstanceID] * in_pos;

}
```

and set `baseinstance` in `glDrawElementsInstancedBaseInstance` to instance numbers to draw.

```
for(int r_index = 0; r_index < instance_id_list; r_index++) {
    glDrawElementsInstancedBaseInstance(
            GL_TRIANGLES,      // type of primitive to render
            3,                 // vertex count
            GL_UNSIGNED_INT,   // type of each index in the GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER
            (void*)0,          // element array buffer offset
            1,                 // Number of copies to render
            instance_id_list[r_index]  // Number to start from for InstanceId
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot quite discard individual instances on the GPU in a way you imagine. You shall instead aggregate the IDs of the instances you want to render, and issue rendering commands for those instances.

The command that can draw a specific instance is `glDrawElementsInstancedBaseInstance`, which you can call in a loop:

```
for(auto instance = 0; instance < drawable_vector.size(); instance++)
    if(drawable_vector[instance])
        glDrawElementsInstancedBaseInstance(mode, count, type, indices, 1 /* one instance */, instance);
```

You can also combine all these calls to a single call to `glDrawElementsIndirect` by packing those parameters to a `GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER`:

```
vector<DrawElementsIndirectCommand> draw_indirect;
for(auto instance = 0; instance < drawable_vector.size(); instance++)
    if(drawable_vector[instance])
        draw_indirect.push_back({count, 1 /* one instance */, firstIndex, baseVertex, instance});

//glGenBuffers(1, &draw_indirect_buf); // do once during initialization
glBindBuffer(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, draw_indirect_buf);
glBufferData(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, draw_indirect.size() * sizeof(DrawElementsIndirectCommand), draw_indirect_buf.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glDrawElementsIndirect(mode, type, draw_indirect.size(), 0);
```

The content of the `GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER` can also be generated directly on the GPU in a compute shader. This would require uploading `drawable_vector` instead of `draw_indirect`, and that's unlikely to be any better than the above code.

**EDIT:** Since you're fetching the instance data through an SSBO rather than a VAO, you would need to adjust your instance id calculation. The formula that OpenGL uses is:

```
gl_InstanceID/divisor + gl_BaseInstance
```

Notice that `gl_InstanceID` doesn't include the base-instance that we specify in each of the draw calls/commands, so it's going to be zero. Therefore your shader should use `gl_BaseInstance` instead, or a combination thereof:

```
gl_Position = projection * view * buffer_data.in_models[gl_BaseInstance + gl_InstanceID] * in_pos;
```

However, `gl_BaseInstance` was introduced in the [ARB_shader_draw_parameters](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_draw_parameters.txt) extension, and was made core in OpenGL 4.6, so you may not have it available. Without `gl_BaseInstance` you cannot know the actual instance from within the shader when using the multi-draw or base-instance APIs. If you're stuck with an older OpenGL version, you'll need to resort to passing your MVP matrices through VAO instance attributes instead of an SSBO.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `glDrawElementsInstancedBaseInstance(GL_TRIANGLES,3,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,(void*)0,1,instance)` but it shows only 1 object. Even with two calls it's still showing 1 object. Do I need to setup anything else?

Comment: @KennyTan your shaders and VAO should be set up correctly too -- but you didn't include those in the question.

Comment: @KennyTan are you using `gl_InstanceID` to fetch the instance data from an SSBO? Beware that t doesn't include the base-instance -- so all `gl_InstanceID` will be zero; you shall use `gl_BaseInstance + gl_InstanceID` to determine the actual instance.

Comment: I can draw all instances with `glDrawArraysInstanced` so the shaders and VAO are set up correctly. What is the `gl_BaseInstance` anyway? is that the `binding_index` in the SSBO setup?

Comment: @KennyTan it may be "set up correctly" for the simple case of `glDrawArraysInstanced`, but not correct enough for the general case. `glDrawArraysInstanced` assumes `gl_BaseInstance == 0` and `gl_InstanceID` will go through `0, 1, ..., instanceCount-1`. With this setup, however, `gl_BaseInstance` will get values from the `0, 1, ..., instanceCount-1` set, and `gl_InstanceID` will be zero. OpenGL uses `gl_BaseInstance + gl_InstanceID` for fetching instanced attributes from a VAO, but you need to take `gl_BaseInstance` into account if you fetch your vertex data manually from an SSBO.

Comment: No, it's not related to `binding_index` in any way.

Comment: I just update the code in the questions. Can you check if I'm doing correctly? Many thanks @Yakov Galka.

Comment: Thanks @Yakoc Galka for your guide, I managed to make it.